# Как предотвратить закачку дубликата в БД после проверки данных?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, pandas, dataframe

Я осуществляю проверку данных с помощью написания запроса к БД MS SQL через Python:

```
params = urllib.parse.quote_plus("DRIVER={SQL Server Native Client 11.0};SERVER=сервер;DATABASE=БД;UID=логин;PWD=пароль")
qry = """SELECT * FROM [таблица] WHERE [столбец] = ?"""
params = [pd.to_datetime("2020-07-20")]
df = pd.read_sql(qry, conn, params=params)
```

Здесь если я вижу, что данные возвращаются, то они уже есть в БД, а если нет, то продолжаю закачку.

Сейчас делаю полное веб приложение с графическим интерфейсом для коллег не IT.
Надо чтобы программа сама смотрела, если что-то выходит, то выводить предупреждение, что данные уже есть и возвращатся на первоначальную стадию закачки.

Как осуществить в коде данное условие?

Comment: Вопрос в том как проверить пустой ли датафрейм?

Comment: да, немного посложнее нужно закачать файл csv и во время его закачки сравнить  дату в столбике csv с датой в БД, но это должно быть не прописью, а алгоритмом.Если во время проверки обнаруживается что-то в базе, то pop-up window-предупреждение, что нельзя закачивать, если ничего не выходит, то процесс начинается процесс обработки. Сейчас переношу весь код с Jupyter на Atom, чтобы было полноценное приложение на Plotly Dash

Comment: Т.е. нужно проверить есть ли в CSV файле хотя бы одна дата, которая уже есть в таблице SQL сервера - я правильно понял?

Comment: Уточните пожалуйста - «закачка CSV» - это загрузка данных из CSV в таблицу или нечто другое?

Comment: да. И сейчас сложность в том, что до этого я прописывала все поля самостоятельно и части кода тоже запускала отдельно на Jupyter, сейчас все нужно запускать вместе и чтобы не вписывать поля, а был автоматизированный алгоритм.

Comment: какой результат вы хотите получить если в CSV файле (скажем с 1000 строк) всего одна-две строки с датой дубликатом?

Comment: Это, не загрузка в БД, а сначала загрузка в веб-приложение Plotly dash через кнопку upload file. Я сейчас разбираюсь с этим, поэтому за базу взяла данный код с официального сайта https://dash.plotly.com/dash-core-components/upload

Comment: результат должен быть предупреждающее окно, на подобии : "Такая дата уже есть продолжить обработку файла Да/Нет  "

Comment: По-моему мы друг друга не понимаем... Что значит продолжить обработку файла? Мы или закачаем весь файл целиком или не будем закачивать ничего. Поэтому я и спрашивал какой алгоритм действий если в большом CSV файле почти все даты новые, но есть несколько строк, которые  дублируются ?

Comment: а, нет, такого не может быть. Каждый файл генерируется отдельно за некий период дней. То есть не может быть такого, что в новом файле часть дат догружается от предыдущего файла.

Comment: Т.е. минимальная дата в файле должна быть больше максимальной даты в БД?

Comment: сейчас уточнила, нет. могут данные с предыдущего дня догружать

Comment: я окончательно запутался... можете привести примеры дат, которые могут встречаться в БД и в CSV файле? Так чтобы было понятно какие варианты встречаются...

Comment: в csv файле дата такого формата: 07.20.2020 00:00:00, а в БД уже такого 2020-07-20. Графический интерфейс создается для того проекта, к которому я здесь до этого еще много вопросов задавала и вы помогали мне их решать. ^.^

Comment: @MaxU простите пожалуйста за беспокойство, но мне показалось, что у вас есть некоторые идеи на предмет данного вопроса. Вы можете пожалуйста их написать, я просто немного не понимаю, в какую сторону мыслить, чтоб решить данную проблему.

Comment: для того, чтобы что-то посоветовать надо понимать о чем конретно идет речь, какие могут быть сценарии/случаи. На данный момент я этого не понимаю - поэтому  и попросил привести приеры нескольких случаев. Например в БД последняя дата 2020-09-01, в CSV файле минимальная дата 2020-08-31. Что делаем в этом случае - полностью игнорируем __все__ данные из CSV файла и т.д. ...

Comment: @MaxU Прошу прощения за поздний ответ, сценарий может быть таким: последняя дата в БД: 2020-08-31, пришли данные за 2020-08-20- код проверяет есть ли такая дата в БД и ее нет-значит мы закачиваем данные. Если пришел файл с данными, но там несколько дат: 2020-09-02;09-03;09-04 код проверяет даты - их нет- закачиваем данные. Не может быть такого что в файле есть даты которых закачали и не закачали, например не может быть такого, что в одном файле даты за 2020-09-04(мы такое уже закачивали) и 2020-09-05; 09-06(данные мы не закачивали за эти 2 даты).

Comment: @MaxU Показатели в необработанном файле записываются каждый час, то есть в необработанном файле за 2020-08-31 все данные записываются в таком формате: 2020-08-31 01:00:00; 2020-08-31 02:00:00 и тд, а в БД они уже хранятся в 2020-08-31, так как все показатели за 24 часа складываются. С преобразованием дат, вы помогли мне разобраться. Данный вопрос является продолжением этого вопроса shorturl.at/cglsW

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Если вопрос в том как проверить пустой ли датафрейм:

```
if df.empty:
    ...
```

или

```
if len(df) == 0:
    ...
```

Comment: Ответ правильный, но я не до конца раскрыла вопрос. Я вам оставила комментарий выше.

Comment: @MRO _Я вам оставила комментарий выше_, не оставляйте комментарии, ни выше, ни ниже.  Вносите улучшающую правку в сам вопрос, комментарии не являются его составной частью и обычно удаляются.

Answer (score 2):

Ответ на дополнения из комментариев.

Для того, чтобы проверить есть ли в файле даты, которые уже существуют в таблице БД можно сделать так:

1. вычитать все уникальные даты из таблицы БД
2. вычитать все дату/время из CSV файла, отрезать время, превратив значения в дату
3. найти пересечение этих двух множеств - если пересечение множеств непустое, значит хотя бы одна дата из CSV файла уже существует в таблице БД.

---

Код:

```
qry = """SELECT DISTINCT date_column_name as dt FROM table_name"""
db_dates = pd.read_sql(qry, conn)
csv_dates = pd.to_datetime(df["date"], errors="coerce").dt.floor("D").unique()
intersctn = set(db_dates["dt"]) & set(csv_dates)

if intersctn:
    # пересечение непустое
    ...
else:
    # пересечение пустое
    ...
```

Comment: Спасибо! Буду сейчас пробовать.